# SQL transpose Columns containing aggregate functions into Rows?

Tags: sql, transpose

I have a list of columns each with specific conditions and an alias, however I cannot use UNPIVOT to transpose the columns into rows as the columns don't have names (cannot reference the newly created alias either). Also, copy pasting the columns into the UNPIVOT func throws an error as it expects column names, not selections with aggregate funcs.

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN reknr = 4103
    THEN bdr_val END) AS "4103",
    SUM(CASE WHEN reknr = 4303
    THEN bdr_val END) AS "4303",
    SUM(CASE WHEN reknr = 4309
    THEN bdr_val END) AS "4309",
    etc. etc.

FROM
    gbkmut

WHERE --Other conditions they should adhere to
    datum BETWEEN '20220701' AND '20220731'
    AND transtype in ('N', 'C', 'P')
    etc. etc.
```

Is there a simple way to transpose such a selection of columns?

Comment: Hi, why not sum bdr_val and group by reknr and pivot that?

Comment: Thanks bro, you just saved me so much time. 
BTW no need to PIVOT if you group by.